# How to integrate Association Rules to new Dataset

Tags: r, arules, market-basket-analysis

I generated a list of Rules using arules in R on a transactional dataset.
Now, I have a new dataset with a list of customer and the list of products they bought over the past 2 months.

My goal is to recommend new relevant products to those customers using the rules I got from the transactional data. 
But I can't find a way to automically apply a recommendation(rules) to a customer based on its purchases.

Any advices would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at package recommenderlab. [This document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf) shows how to do what you would like to do.